# Elasticsearch NEST API - querying the right index

Tags: c#, search, elasticsearch, nest

Using the C# NEST API on Elasticsearch:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Product>(s => s
                .Index(Constants.ElasticSearchIndex)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Raw(jsonRequest)
                )
            );
```

The query is supposed to run on the /sc_all/ index, but it runs on /sc_all/product/ index (which doesn't exist - /product/ seems to be added because of the Search since T = product).

If I do like this, /product/ is replaced with the value of the constant, i.e. /sc_all/product/ => /sc_all/constant_value/:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Product>(s => s
                .Index(Constants.ElasticSearchIndex)
                .Type(Constants.ElasticSearchType)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Raw(jsonRequest)
                )
            );
```

What should I do if I just want to query /sc_all/ and nothing else?

Thanks!

---

Json request:

"{\"filtered\": {\"query\": {\"match_all\": { }},\"filter\": {\"nested\" : {\"path\" : \"products\",\"filter\": {\"nested\" : {\"path\" : \"products.da\",\"filter\": { \"bool\": { \"must\": [{\"query\": {\"query_string\": {\"default_field\" : \"products.da.content\", \"query\" : \"kildemoes\"}}}]}}}}}}}}, \"from\": 0, \"size\": 100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify to run across all types with `.AllTypes()`

```
var jsonRequest = "{ \"match_all\": {} }";

var searchResults = client.Search<Product>(s => s
                        .Index(Constants.ElasticSearchIndex)
                        .AllTypes()
                        .Query(q => q
                            .Raw(jsonRequest)
                        )
                    );
```

which will generate the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/sc_all/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
```

Bear in mind that any documents returned will attempt to be deserialized into instances of `Product` so if you will be targeting multiple different types, you may want to use a common base type or `dynamic` and additionally, take advantage of [covariant search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/covariant-search-results.html).

Comment: Thanks, but my Json request already contains a "match_all". I have added it to my question above.

Comment: @Louisa I think you've missed the point - if you specify `.AllTypes()` on the body of the search request, then you will be searching across all types in the index `Constants.ElasticSearchIndex`. I added an example value for `jsonRequest` so the code you've given will compile.

Answer (score 0):

You were using an outdated version client, like 5.x.
I came across the same problem too using 5.x. The second subpath is the document type, which is the `_type` name of your document and is `docs` by default. So, the solution I use is to add `[ElasticsearchType(Name = "docs")]` at the top of my POCO class and the search path will is something like `/{indexname}/docs/_search`, and it's fine.